# Click on a link and go to another element on the same page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have

```
  <button>  <a href="#x">More</a> </button>
```

and I have `<div  id="x"> </div>`

But when I click on link, my page before going to desired div reloads(

I can't reproduce this behaviour on jsfiddle because there it works fine.
Can this be because I am using rails an turned turbolinks off?
If you need I can deploy the code to the server but I haven't done this yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set data-turbolinks as false for that href tag.

> data-turbolinks="false"

```
 <a href="#x" data-turbolinks="false"></a>
```

Trying this might solve the issue.